# binding a custom property class WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I got a custom WPF property class named "RFPGegevens"

```
public class RFPGegevens
{
    private string _klant;
    public String Klant
    {
        get { return _klant; }
        set { _klant = value; }
    }
 }
```

In my ViewModel I got a property RFPGegevens

```
    private RFPGegevens _rfpGegevens;

    public RFPGegevens RfpGegevens
    {
        get
        {
            if (_rfpGegevens == null)
                _rfpGegevens = new RFPGegevens();
            return _rfpGegevens;
        }
        set
        {
            _rfpGegevens = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("RfpGegevens");
        }
    }
```

This property is filled correctly, if I debug this is the result:

[image]

In my View I'm binding the property "RFPGegevens" to the datacontext of my Grid

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RfpGegevens}">
```

and still if I debug the "Klant" property field is filled.

[image]

But as I bind this property in the View my textbox is still empty.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Klant, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I also tried this but nothings seems to work:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RFPGegevens.Klant, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Where did you debug the get-accessor? Is it ensured, that it is called by the WPF, for the TextBox-Binding? What does the output-window in VS say about the binding, when running?

Comment: Did you set the windows datacontext binding correct?

Comment: Does your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged, i see you are calling the base.RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: I implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged and the windows datacontext is bound correctly. And for Andreas can you restate your question pls?

Comment: So if you put a textbox outside the grid it bind's correct? And just a quick check.. <TextBox Text="{Binding RFPGegevens.Klant, Mode=TwoWay}"/> uses RFP while your prop is named Rfp

Comment: Tried to set it outside the grid and that doens't changes mutch, same for the second suggestion. Quick comment my textbox is located in a tabitem wich I made in a different userControl I bound it due a dataTemplate.

Comment: Only thing i can think of is that your windows datacontext isn't inherited correct. Check this link and try it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658397/wpf-datagrid-header-text-binding

Comment: @jrb the datacontext is set on the Grid so the items in the grid will inherit it and he could use it correctly i guess the problem will be somewhere with the INotifyPropertyChanged interface maybe you should implement it on your class too the way Vijay suggests.

Comment: My datacontext is indeed bound correctly cause I show a list in my screen which is bound in the ViewModel. It's just the custom made prop class which isn't doing it's work. I tried to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged in the class itself but that doesn't made any diff.

Comment: As a diagnostic step, try setting the `Text` property to `"{Binding}"` - this will display the type name of the current `DataContext` in the `TextBox` and should allow you to work out what binding path you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with two things

`<TextBox Text="{Binding Klant, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

```
public class RFPGegevens
{
    private string _klant;
    public String Klant
    {
        get { return _klant; }
        set {
              _klant = value; 
              //Raise the property changed event here
            }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for your custom class also as below:

```
public class RFPGegevens : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

and raise the propertychanged events from the set accessor of your properties.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add inheritance from INotifyPropertyChanged