# Bind data to TextBox inside DataGridTextColumn.Header

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<RepairInfo> RepairList { get; set; }
```

And I'm binding it to a `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding RepairList}" Name="RepairsGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

I don't use all properties of my `RepairInfo` class so I specify which property have to use each columns, like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IMEI}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <TextBox MinWidth="90" Text="{Binding IMEIFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>                
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The `TextBox` inside `DataGridTextColumn.Header` using for filtering data.

So here is my problem - value from `TextBox` don't update property in `ViewModel`. If I put this `TextBox` outside `DataGridTextColumn.Header` everything is fine. I guess it causes by `Binding` property of my `DataGridTextColumn` but I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Can you show the viewmodel here.

Comment: It's pretty huge , so I share it on googleDrive https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wt4AJ49E-cr9du6T7QKgbFaOMoqVnG10WSaJyReMrOs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try to bind with DataContext prefix. Something like this : <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DataContext.IMEI}">...

Comment: I feel its not problem with binding or view model. Its more to do with how the header template is defined here. My guess is some kind of data template should be defined to fix this.

Comment: @dantey89  Can you tell me, which class the `IMEI` and `IMEIFilter` resides?  I will help me to give the solution in more precise way.  Thanks

Comment: @dantey89 Have you tried the solution?

Comment: ImeiFilter - is a string property in ViewModel wich contains text from the TextBox for future filtering. IMEI - is a property of RepairInfo wich was closed ObservableCollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO. .  better way would be having the property for the `Header` inside the MainWindow Viewmodel and you can `Bind` it like this

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IMEI}"> 
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <TextBox MinWidth="90" Text="{Binding DataContext.IMEIFilter, 
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
```

***Reference:***  [WPF datagrid header text binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658397/wpf-datagrid-header-text-binding)

Comment: I read linked post and refactor code to this `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IMEI}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox MinWidth="90" Text="{Binding DataContext.IMEIFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>                
                </DataGridTextColumn>` and it's work now!

Comment: The main thing was to add this code `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}` to the TextBox so it can undertand where to put value