# Bind DataGrid Headers Text to properties in WPF MVVM at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a datagrid whose column headers I would like to change during runtime. I have tried something like this but doesn't work

```
    <DatagridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=MyNewHeader}" Binding=" {Binding Path=MyBindingProperty}" />
```

And In my MVVM

```
    string myHeaderProperty;
    public string MyHeaderProperty{
    get{
    return myHeaderProperty 
    }
    set{
    Set(ref myHeaderProperty, value);
    }
```

But does not work. Any Ideas will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF datagrid header text binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658397/wpf-datagrid-header-text-binding)

Comment: Doesn't work. What would be `DataContext[0].DisplayName` in the view model? Can XAML be able to translate `DataContext[0]`? I just have a simple property in ViewModel like so 

        `string column1;`
       `public string Column1{
get{...}
set{...}
 }`

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45430214/1292254

Answer (score 1):

This should work provided that `MyHeaderProperty` belongs to the `DataContext` of the parent `DataGrid`, i.e. the view model:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyBindingProperty}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyHeaderProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look in the output window you will see that you probably get a binding expression exception because MyNewHeader is not a property on you item in the row.

So you need to bind it to the parent via relativesource binding

Take a look at the following example 
https://wpftutorial.net/BindingExpressions.html