# I can't use localization on datagrid headers

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, header

This combobox can change my button's content perfectly.

```
<ComboBox Margin="2 0 0 0" x:Name="languageComboBox" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage,Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="English" Tag="en-US"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Japanese" Tag="jp-JP" />
            </ComboBox>
```

My problem is, i can't change datagrid's column headers.

```
 </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn HeaderStringFormat="{Binding Id}" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn HeaderStringFormat="{Binding Name}" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn HeaderStringFormat="{Binding Address}" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

For example, when i bind Id variable to a label's content It works. I tried to many methods to change header contents but they does not work somehow.

Tried this.

```
 </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn HeaderStringFormat="{Binding Id}" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn HeaderStringFormat="{Binding Name}" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn HeaderStringFormat="{Binding Address}" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

And this.

```
 </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Id}" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Name}" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Address}" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

I get this error for Id variable ->

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
> or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
> BindingExpression:Path=Id; DataItem=null; target element is
> 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=654914); target property is
> 'HeaderStringFormat' (type 'String')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF datagrid header text binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658397/wpf-datagrid-header-text-binding)

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value1}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.ColumnTitel1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

Comment: I have tried this. This one throws no errors but still doesn't work. `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value1}"> <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate> <DataTemplate> <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.ColumnTitel1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/> </DataTemplate> </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate> </DataGridTextColumn>` and i don't know how to use that class in xaml.  [DataContextSpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658397/wpf-datagrid-header-text-binding)

Comment: Follow the link. Read the posts.  The reason binding does not work in a header because it doesn't have datacontext inherited as you might expect.