# WPF: Binding DataGrid column header to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, data-binding, gridview

I have a datagrid in which i manually specify the columns (AutoGenerateColumns="false"). I'm using MVVM and I would like to bind the column header (the text) so that I get it from my ViewModel. But I can't find a way to do that.

The closest thing I've found is this:
[Wpf Toolkit. Bind DataGrid Column Header to DynamicResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652240/wpf-toolkit-bind-datagrid-column-header-to-dynamicresource)
...which is a "trick" with which you can bind the column header to a string statically declared in XAML. But I need to get it from my ViewModel.

The reason I want to this is that the text I want to use as column header will be shown in several places throughout the GUI. To get make sure it actually is the same everywhere I want to have it available in code. And I can't store the strings in a XAML resource file because I also need access to these strings in code.

I'm using a RadGridView from TeleRik, but I guessing I'd have the same problem if I the standard gridview.

Any tips appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Silverlight I have tried the following:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.MyProperty}" ... />
```

(LayoutRoot is the first control in the Window/UserControl, MyProperty is something in the VM)
It does not work because the column has no access to the visual tree.

It may be worth a try in WPF with your Grid.

Comment: Did not work for me in WPF 4.5.  Error "Framework mentor not found".  I was using a DataGridTemplateColumn