# WPF DataGrid - Databinding Column to Page's ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to bind a data on one of my columns to data that's in my page's ViewModel (as opposed to the objects that the grid is bound to).

What I have below was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726094/wpf-binding-datagrid-column-header-to-viewmodel), to no avail.

```
   <DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.JUNK}"></Button>
         </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In my ViewModel

```
public string JUNK { get; set; }
```

Which is set to `"HELLO"` in the ViewModel's constructor

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here's the entire XAML.  Relevant column is all the way at the bottom, in the grid within the grid

**ALSO** - I'm having trouble getting my entire source into here again (not sure if it's citrix or what) but I took that *same exact binding expression* that's not working in the datagrid's button, and I dropped it onto the Text of a plain old TextBlock apart from the grid, and it worked like a charm.  I also added a new dummy text column to the grid, and used that same binding expression for the text, and it still did *not* work.  It seems this binding expression is fine, but refuses to work anywhere near the grid.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainApp.WPF.ucFmvHistoryDisplayGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="1000" x:Name="LayoutRoot">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Name="rightAlignedColumn" x:Key="rightAlignedColumn" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Name="centerAlignedColumn" x:Key="centerAlignedColumn" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dbTop" ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyGroupSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" Width="800">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="120" Header="Property Num" Binding="{Binding PropertyNum}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="120" Header="Alt Description" Binding="{Binding AltDescription}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="80" Header="County" Binding="{Binding County}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="State" Binding="{Binding State}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource centerAlignedColumn}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="85" Header="Phase" Binding="{Binding Phase}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="85" Header="FMV" Binding="{Binding FmvTotal}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Assessed Value" Binding="{Binding AssessedValueTotal}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <DataGrid Margin="5" Background="White" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyFmvSource}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="125" Header="County Acct Num" Binding="{Binding Property.CountyAccountNum, StringFormat=d}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource rightAlignedColumn}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="80" Header="City" Binding="{Binding Property.City, StringFormat=d}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource rightAlignedColumn}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="80" Header="Jurisdiction" Binding="{Binding Property.Jurisdiction, StringFormat=d}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource rightAlignedColumn}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="80" Header="FMV Date" Binding="{Binding MostRecentFMV.FMVDate, StringFormat=d}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource rightAlignedColumn}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="FMV" Binding="{Binding MostRecentFMV.FMV, StringFormat=N0}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource rightAlignedColumn}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="85" Header="Assess Ratio" Binding="{Binding MostRecentFMV.AssessmentRatio, StringFormat=N3}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource rightAlignedColumn}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="105" Header="Assessed Value" Binding="{Binding MostRecentFMV.AssessedValue, StringFormat=N0}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource rightAlignedColumn}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Content="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.JUNK}"></Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Do you have an element named "LayoutRoot", on which you've set the DataContext to your ViewModel? Could you post a little more XAML (specifically the definition of the "LayoutRoot" element)? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a WPF expert at all, but isn't LayoutRoot built in - isn't that automatically the top-most UI element in scope?  Or is that just completely wrong and I need to add a name of LayoutRoot to said UI element?  Actually, I can see fairly clearly that's the case.  Just write that in an answer and I'll close this up.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, no, it didn't.  I was convinced it would.  Updating the question now...

Comment: +1, very good question. I'm very surprised by this behavior and the answer I posted isn't a very good solution but it's the only one I can think of. I have no idea why it doesn't work with ElementName or RelativeSource but I'll be observing this question to see if someone comes up with a better explanation or workaround for this :)

Comment: @Adam Rackis: See my updated answer for a workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding to the DataContext of the containing DataGrid using a RelativeSource binding should work:

```
<Button Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=DataContext.JUNK}"></Button>
```

As you've nested the DataGrids, the AncestorLevel must be set to "2" to Bind to the DataContext of the outermost DataGrid.

Comment: Wow - it was that simple.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh wow, this really helped me style a DataGrid column using view models binding +1.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

@Danny Shisler's answer is correct. Leaving this answer since it shows how to do Bindings inside of `DataGridColumn` which isn't in the Visual Tree and doesn't have a DataContext

---

Here is a blog post that presents a workaround for this issue: http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/josh_smith/archive/2008/06/26/data-binding-the-isvisible-property-of-contextualtabgroup.aspx

The workaround is to create a DataContextSpy that looks like this

**DataContextSpy**

```
public class DataContextSpy
: Freezable // Enable ElementName and DataContext bindings
{
    public DataContextSpy()
    {
        // This binding allows the spy to inherit a DataContext.
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, DataContextProperty, new Binding());
    }

    public object DataContext
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataContextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Borrow the DataContext dependency property from FrameworkElement.
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataContextProperty =
        FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(DataContextSpy));

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        // We are required to override this abstract method.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then you can use an instance of `DataContextSpy` as the Source for the Bindings in the `DataGridColumn`s like this

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:DataContextSpy x:Key="dataContextSpy" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid ...>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.JUNK,
                                           Source={StaticResource dataContextSpy}}">
                <!--..-->
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <!--..-->
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It may not have a data context, but it still supports DataBinding, doesn't it?  In the columns when binding text to a column (or a button) wouldn't the same binding expressions work as anywhere else?  Sorry, again, I'm not a WPF expert.

Comment: @Adam Rackis: The problem as I see it has nothing to do with DataContext. I agree with you, and I can't see any reason for your the Binding in your question not to work. I tried a bunch of different ways of getting this to work but they all failed when using RelativeSource or ElementName

Comment: Bah - I guess it's not just me then - hopefully something will come up.  I don't want to go stringing this together in the code behind if possible.

Comment: @Adam Rackis: Clarifying my comment. It has nothing to do with the DataContext of the `Button`

Comment: ok - thanks again for the help.  I'll upvote your answer either way once I can get this resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Might be Monday morning before I get back to this - thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, and all the work you put into writing it.  +1, but I have to accept the RelativeSource/Ancestor Binding answer.  Much simpler for me to implement.  Thanks again again!

Comment: @Adam Rackis: I couldn't get RelativeSource to work but if it's working for you then that's the way to go for sure!