# How do I bind the foreground color of a label in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have a wpf datagrid with a label in a datatemplate.  I want to bind the color of the text to a property and it's not working.

Here is the xaml.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ResultsDataGrid" CanUserSortColumns="True"  MouseDown="ResultsDataGrid_OnMouseDown" SelectionChanged="ResultsDataGrid_OnSelectionChanged" 
IsReadOnly="False" AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test ID" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True" SortMemberPath="TestDate">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Foreground="{Binding PassedColor}"  Content="{Binding TestID}"></Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And here is the property.

```
public Brush PassedColor
{
    get
    {
        return new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

If it remove the binding and set the foreground to `red` it works.  So it's definitely something with the binding.

Edit:

Here is the entire object

```
public class LabelInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isSelected;
    private double? _karat;
    private bool _passed;
    public string TestID { get; set; }
    public string Label1 { get; set; }
    public string Label2 { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string HasPassed { get { return Passed ? "Yes" : "No"; } }

    public Brush PassColor
    {
        get
        {
            return Brushes.Red;
        }
    }

    public bool Passed
    {
        get { return _passed; }
        set
        {
            _passed = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool Final { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TestDate { get; set; }
    public Double RealTime { get; set; }
    public string JTVID { get; set; }
    public int AnalysisID { get; set; }
    public List<ElementResults> Elements { get; set; }
    public double Karat
    {
        get
        {
            if (_karat == null)
                _karat = CalculateKarat();
            return _karat.Value;
        }
        set { _karat = value; }
    }

    public bool PlatingAlert
    {
        get
        {
            return Karat < 7.5;
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set { _isSelected = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public bool PotentialCoating { get; set; }

    private double CalculateKarat()
    {
        if (Elements == null || Elements.Count == 0) return 0;
        return Elements.Where(ex => ex.Name.ToLower().Trim() == "au").Select(ex => ex.Level).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need `DataContextSpy`, see this link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046436/wpf-datagrid-databinding-column-to-pages-viewmodel The problem is because that's not part of the visual tree, so you can't access a binding there.

Comment: Besides the `DataContext` you'll need to use the `INoifyPropertyChanged`interface. But, IMHO, I'll use a ResourceDictionary for that.

Comment: @Tico You'll need to do that only if you really need a property change notification mechanism. That's not the problem here.

Comment: @gleng, thanks for the help, but I'm not binding to the viewcontext.  The text binding is working fine.

Comment: @Clemens Sure, but if you use it in a DataContext, it won't change.

Comment: @Tice, this property has no setter.  Just a getter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `System.Drawing.Brush`, which is from WinForms, but you should use the WPF `System.Windows.Media.Brush`. Change your code to this:

```
using System.Windows.Media;

public Brush PassedColor
{
    get { return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); }
}
```

or

```
public Brush PassedColor
{
    get { return Brushes.Red; }
}
```

---

Perhaps remove `System.Drawing` from the referenced assemblies. Then you'll immediately find all those flaws.

Comment: Hmm, no go.  I've changed it to return a color instead of a brush, but still no luck.  But I think you're on the right track.  I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: Do not return a Color, return `System.Windows.Media.Brush` instead of `System.Drawing.Brush`.

Comment: Still nothing.  I'm going to play with changing a label foreground in code behind and see if I can get it work outside of a grid first.

Comment: Yes, it is.  Also, media brush worked fine outside of the datagrid (so that's the right class).  This is very odd.

Comment: And (dumb question) both `TestID` and `PassedColor` are public properties in the same data item (aka view model) class?

Comment: I added the entire class to my question if that helps

Comment: Now the property is called `PassColor`, not `PassedColor`. That simple?

Comment: It "used" to be `PassedColor`.  It looks like I messed it up at some point during our conversation.  Thanks for your time.  I'm going to slam my hand in a drawer now.