# Bind DataGrid Column Header

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wpf Toolkit. Bind DataGrid Column Header to DynamicResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652240/wpf-toolkit-bind-datagrid-column-header-to-dynamicresource)
>   [WPF Error: Cannot find govering FrameworkElement for target element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660967/wpf-error-cannot-find-govering-frameworkelement-for-target-element)

I am creating a WPF application using the MVVM pattern, so on my view I am trying to bind the column header of a `DataGrid` column to a property on my view model which is the data context of the view that the `DataGrid` is in.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="DailyData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DailyDataViewModels}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding InflowVolumeLabel}" Binding="{Binding InflowVolume}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

However the header just shows up blank and does not seem to be trying to bind to the specified property, how can you bind a `DataGrid` column header?

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: The `BindingMarkupExtension` considers any unkeyed value to be the `Path`, so yes it is intentional, but it also is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into a neat problem with the `DataGrid.Columns` collection, namely they are not a member of the same visual tree and thus only the `Binding` property appears to work.

The only approach I've found that works is to add an attached property to the `DataGrid` which will apply the headers after the data is loaded.

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnHeadersProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ColumnHeaders",
        typeof(IDictionary<string, string>),
        typeof(DataGrid),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(
            new Dictionary<string,string>(),
            ColumnHeadersPropertyChanged));

public static IDictionary<string,string> GetColumnHeaders(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (IDictionary<string, string>)obj.GetValue(ColumnHeadersProperty);
}

public static void SetColumnHeaders(DependencyObject obj,
    IDictionary<string, string> value)
{
    obj.SetValue(ColumnHeadersProperty, value);
}

static void ColumnHeadersPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dataGrid != null && e.NewValue != null)
    {
        dataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += AddColumnHeaders;
    }
}

static void AddColumnHeaders(object sender,
    DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    var headers = GetColumnHeaders(sender as DataGrid);
    if (headers.ContainsKey(e.PropertyName))
    {
        e.Column.Header = headers[e.PropertyName];
    }
}
```

Potentially used like (could be improved):

```cs
// you could change it to use Column.DisplayIndex
this.dataGrid.SetValue(
    DataGridEx.ColumnHeadersProperty,
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "PropertyName1", "Header 1" },
        { "PropertyName2", "Header 2" },
        { "PropertyName3", "Header 3" },
    });
```